# Finding the form of a differential map restricted to a given space

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, surfaces, tangent-spaces

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3, f(x,y,z) = (x^2+y,y^3+2z,z^2)$. I have to find how does the differential of $f$ restricted to the tangent plane to the unit sphere $S^1$ in an arbitrary point $(x_0,y_0,z_0) \in S^1$ look.

I've done some work and I've found that the equation of the tangent plane to the unit sphere $S^1$ in an arbitrary point $(x_0,y_0,z_0) \in S^1$ is
$$x_0x+y_0y+z_0z = 1$$
and the differential of $f$ in general is given by the Jacobian matrix, but I don't know how to find the form of $Df$ restricted to the plane above. Can someone give me a hint, please?

Comment: Without loss of generality, $z_0=1.$ Then, with  $i:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^3:(x,y)\mapsto (x,y,1-x_0x-y_0y);\ p\in S^2$ you want to compute $d_p(f\circ i)=d_{i(p)}f\circ d_pi$  so calculate  the Jacobian of the two maps